# How to configure coderunner extension to execute ts

Tags: typescript, vscode-code-runner, coderunner

i understand that's a rookie question, but i failed to find an answer to it.

For making my tests easier I need to run small parts of my code and, after some search, I found the code runner extension for VsCode to do it.
An example is the following:

```
import { getContractAddress } from './useContract';
const contractAddress = getContractAddress(1);
console.log({ contractAddress });
```

For some conceptual reason, this file is triggered hourly and changing that is tricky. So, I just need to test this 3 lines for checking the value that's returned.

I assumed this should be really easy but I'm always having errors

```
[Running] ts-node "/Users/guest/Documents/GitHub/frontend/src/tempCodeRunnerFile.ts" /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^ TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: src/tempCodeRunnerFile.ts(1,1): error TS1208: 'tempCodeRunnerFile.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.
```

Can you explain how to configure coderunner to run ts?
I found several stuff explaining it to JS, but nothing to TS.
I admit I'm newbie in web dev and coderunner, so don't be afraid of over explain it.,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bun treats TypeScript as a first-class citizen.

The easiest way is to...

- [install bun](https://bun.sh/docs/installation#installing)
- set `bun` as the executor for code-runner typescript.

  ```json
  "code-runner.executorMap": {
    "typescript": "bun $fullFileName",
  },
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to install the **ts-node globally** using this command but the **tasks.json** file in the .vscode folder and **tsconfig.json** file in the folder location of your typescript files is also required to auto-compile so to achieve this.

Note : **First Install the Code Runner Extesnion** in the VSCode which you can find in the VSCode or here in this [marketplace link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)

1. run this on CMD line in VSCode Folder wherever your typescript files needed to be run you can see point 2 on how to run this cmd -> tsc --init
2. to run above command you can right click on one of the file in a folder where all your typescript files are present and **'open integrated terminal' and in the opened terminal you can run the command -> tsc --init**
3. Due to above command **a file named tsconfig will be created in the folder where you run this command**
4. **Open this tsconfig file and select the 'sourcemap' settings** in this file , it will be commented just **remove the '//' comment before sourcemap** so it will get used
5. Now **click on the terminal option in the vscode at the top** and **select 'configure default build task'** to compile the TS files in the background
6. after selecting 'configure default build task' **select the 'tsc:watch -tsconfig.json' option** and the 'tasks.json' will appear in the window, also the **file explorer will now show the .vscode folder with the tasks.json file**
7. Now **install the ts-node** using the following command in the **terminal and the command** is  -> **npm install -g ts-node**
8. **Now the ts-files are ready to be run by the code runner**, so whenever you **right click anywhere inside the TS file in Vscode** it will show a **'Run' option at the top in the option list select this an run the TS file.**